# MVC 3 Application With ASP.Net Membership Provider Login Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I appear to have an unusual problem -

I've used the aspnet membership provider before without any issues but this just isn't working out for me.

I've added the schema to my database on sql server through the wizard. To configure the application for first use I run a script that fills the database with some sample accounts, roles, and other information.

After I run this script, I can login in within the application with the newly created usernames, use the features, etc. However after a while, or if I close the development server from the task bar, and then launch the application again and try to login - it won't validate the user. It fails the second IF statement to Validate the user and password below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

If I check the database, the user is clearly there, however the incorrect password attempts field is still at 0, which might indicate that the application is not even recognising these as users. Also, If I check the website configuration (VS2010 -> Project -> ASP.NET Configuration) it shows that there are 0 existing users.

If I re-run the application, and run the setup script again, I can log in like before, however after again if I relaunch and try to login again I get the familiar incorrect password/username screen. Sometimes it happens on a different port number however sometimes the port numbers are the same and it still happens.

Here is the setup script:

```
 protected void btnSetUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();

            Membership.ApplicationName = "MyApp";
            Roles.ApplicationName = "MyApp";

            if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
                Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

            if (!Roles.RoleExists("User"))
                Roles.CreateRole("User");

            // Delete all existing users.
            //
            foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
            {
                Membership.DeleteUser(user.UserName, true);
            }


            // Create the master admin account.
            //
            if (Membership.GetUser("admin@MyApp.com") == null)
            {
                MembershipUser adminUser = Membership.CreateUser("admin@MyApp.com", "admin123");
                Roles.AddUserToRole("admin@MyApp.com", "Administrator");
            }

            CreateUser(ctn, "User@MyApp.com", "Joe Bloggs", "Employee", 1);



            ctn.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void CreateUser(ModelContainer ctn, string emailAddress, string Name, string type, int baseShop)
        {
            // Create the User.
            //
            if (Membership.GetUser(emailAddress) == null)
            {
                MembershipUser adminUser = Membership.CreateUser(emailAddress, "admin123");
                Roles.AddUserToRole(emailAddress, "User");

                User u = new User
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    Type = type,
                    BaseShop = baseShop,
                    Login = new Guid(adminUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString())
                };

                ctn.AddToUsers(u);
            }

        }
```

My Web.Config is more or less the default so I'm not sure if it's anything from that but there it is anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyApp;User ID=**;Password=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyApp;user id=**;password=**;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="MyApp" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="MyApp" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="MyApp" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Finding it very hard to be more descriptive of the issue but it's just puzzling. Is there a step I've missed in using the asp.net membership provider? Has anyone else come across this before?

Would be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are using your own custom app in the setup code

```
Membership.ApplicationName = "MyApp";
Roles.ApplicationName = "MyApp";
```

but your web.config is using the default name

```
applicationName="/"
```

Comment: Ah I see it now! I knew it had to be something silly. Thanks a lot :-)